# Hugo rendered incorrect

Tags: hugo

I used Hugo to build my blog as follow procedures:

```
hugo new site my_blog
cd my_blog
hugo new welcome.md
'change the theme'
hugo server --buildDrafts
```

But no posts in the page, there are nothing in the page but the background. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Your new content should be contained in a **section**, like `post`. So the command to add a new blog post would be more like `hugo new post/my-new-post.md`.

If that doesn't work, we need more information about which theme you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This could be several things:

- the content you added (not in a section) will not be used by most themes
- the content you added is still empty, so might not give visible result
- no config file, depending on the theme, you might need to add config options

  hugo new post/welcome.md
  vi post/welcome.md
  hugo -D server